# Creating Bitbucket Server Webhook for AzureDevops Builds

Tags: azure, azure-devops, bitbucket

To keep it short and sweet I am attempting to automate my CI/CD process which includes a AzureDevOps build running automatically when code is pushed in a bitbucket server repo. I have not found any documentation on how to set this up. Does anyone have any experience with this process? Keep in mind (even though i've mentioned it) I am using the server version of Bitbucket while using the PAAS version of AzureDevops.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straightforward. When you create a pipeline, it will ask you where your repo is.

[image: Azure Devops pipelines]

If it's hosted by Atlassian (you access it by https://bitbucket.org), select the BitBucket Cloud one and provide your login.

If it's self hosted, select "Other Git".